# copy contents of immutable map to new mutable map

Tags: scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert immutable.Map to mutable.Map in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042878/how-can-i-convert-immutable-map-to-mutable-map-in-scala)

How do I create a new mutable map with the contents of the immutable map in Scala?

So far I have tried:

```
val m:scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, Double] = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, Double](imm.map({case(key, value) => (key -> value) }))
```

to no avail.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz - Hah, I forgot I answered this one already.

Answer (score 28):

```
val im = Map(1->1.0, 2->3.0)
val mm = collection.mutable.Map[Int,Double]() ++= im
```

Comment: `++` creates another collection, while `++=` adds to the one you've got.  The latter is less wasteful given that the collection is mutable.

Answer (score 10):

```
val immM = Map(1 -> 2)
val mutM = collection.mutable.Map(immM.toSeq: _*)
```