# How to convert list to mutable map with pre processing in Scala?

Tags: list, scala, dictionary

I have a list (size of the list is variable):

```
val ids = List(7, 8, 9)
```

and would like to get the following map:

```
val result= Map("foo:7:bar" -> "val1",
                "foo:8:bar" -> "val1",
                "foo:9:bar" -> "val1")
```

everything in the map is hard-coded except ids and value is the same for everyone, but map has to be mutable, I'd like to update one of its values later:

```
result("foo:8:bar") = "val2"
val result= Map("foo:7:bar" -> "val1",
                "foo:8:bar" -> "val2",
                "foo:9:bar" -> "val1")
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do that like this: First map over the list to produce a list of tuples, then call `toMap` on the result which will make an immutable `Map` out of the tuples:

```
val m = ids.map(id => ("foo:" + id + ":bar", "val1")).toMap
```

Then convert the immutable `Map` to a mutable `Map`, for example like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042878/how-can-i-convert-immutable-map-to-mutable-map-in-scala):

```
val mm = collection.mutable.Map(m.toSeq: _*)
```

**edit** - the intermediate immutable `Map` is not necessary as the commenters noticed, you can also do this:

```
val mm = collection.mutable.Map(ids.map(id => ("foo:" + id + ":bar", "val1")): _*)
```

Comment: It seems unnecessary to first call `toMap` and then `toSeq`.

Comment: This could be simplified somewhat to `collection.mutable.Map(ids map { ix => s"foo:$ix:bar" -> "val1" } : _*)`

Comment: @Shadowlands you may want to convert your comment to an answer, it’s better than the other existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import scala.collection.mutable
val ids = List(7, 8, 9)
val m = mutable.Map[String, String]()
ids.foreach { id => m.update(s"foo:$id:bar", "val1") }

scala> m
Map(foo:9:bar -> val1, foo:7:bar -> val1, foo:8:bar -> val1)
```

You, don't need to create any intermediate objects, that `map` does.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `foldLeft`?

```
ids.foldLeft(mutable.Map.empty[String, String]) { (m, i) => 
  m += (s"foo:$i:bar" -> "val1")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this:

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable
scala> val result = mutable.Map[String, String]()
result: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,String] = Map()

scala> val ids = List(7, 8, 9)
ids: List[Int] = List(7, 8, 9)

scala> for(x <- ids){
     | result("foo:%d:bar".format(x)) = "val1"
     | }

scala> result
res3: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,String] = Map(foo:9:bar -> val1, foo:7:bar -> val1, foo:8:bar -> val1)
```